# Cross and sub domain tracking with Google Analytics Universal Tag

Tags: google-analytics, tags, cross-domain, subdomain, universal

This is my first question on Stackoverflow. So apologies if I make a mistake...

The challenge: I have a website (main.com), a sub-domain (sub.main.com) and 10 websites that send traffic, back and forth, to the main site and the sub domain. Let's call these sites site01.com, site02.com, site03.com,...,site10.com.

My question: How do I implement Universal Tag so I can do cross-domain tracking between main.com, sub.main.com and site01.com, site02.com, site03.com,...,site10.com.

I found instructions on how to do cross domain tracking for two sites. For example, on the main domain I will add the following code:

```
**<!-- Universal Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', 'main.com', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['site01.com']);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>**
```

And on site01.com, I will add the code below:

```
**<!-- Universal Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'site01.com',{'allowLinker': true});
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>**
```

I don't know how to modify the code to include all 10 sites (site01.com, site02.com, site03.com,...,site10.com as part of the cross domain tracking.

Also, in relation to sub-domain tracking, I am guessing that the above code will also capture data from the sub-domain site (sub.main.com) with no issues.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Stratos.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `linker` plugin to all of your sites, otherwise you only track visitors starting at the main domain and from there navigating to your subsites. The other way around (originates from site01.com and browses to your main site) would generate a new `clientId`.

Example (same for all of your sites):

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto', {
    'allowLinker': true
});
ga('send', 'pageview');

// Load the linker plugin and define 
// which domains to autoLink.
ga('require', 'linker');

// NOTE: add all your sites here. you can include the 
// the site the code is at too if you want to use the 
// same array of sites for all of your sites (ie, 
// include this from some shared file)
ga('linker:autoLink', ['main.com', 'site01.com', 'site02.com', 'site03.com']);
```

Use for example the `Google Analytics Debugger` extension to Chrome to verify that you get the same clientId.

**NOTE**: You need to click on an achor-link to the other sites for the autoLinker to work, just typing in the URL in your browser won't work.

For implementing this on forms too pass `true` as a fourth parameter to the `ga('linker:autoLink')`-call above (ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autoforms).